# Ошибка "on a null object reference"

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь вызвать метод который считывает данные из базы и показывает их в ListView (метод располагается в главном классе приложения):

```
public void ShowDB(){
    DatabaseAvrHelper mDatabaseAvrHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase mSqLiteDatabase;
    mDatabaseAvrHelper = new DatabaseAvrHelper(this);
    mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseAvrHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String readQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseAvrHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_AVR;
    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(readQuery, null);
    ArrayAVR.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAvrHelper._ID));
        String Num_ei = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAvrHelper.NUM_EI_COLUMN));
        String Status_Ei = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAvrHelper.STATUS_EI_COLUMN));
        //String Error_Code = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAvrHelper.ERROR_CODE_EI_COLUMN));
        //String Comment_Ei = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAvrHelper.COMMENT_EI_COLUMN));
        Long Date_Ei = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAvrHelper.DATE_EI_COLUMN));
        String dateString = null;
        if (Date_Ei != null) {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM HH:mm");
            dateString = formatter.format(new Date(Date_Ei));
        }
        ArrayAVR.add(0, "№: " + Num_ei + " - " + Status_Ei + " - " + dateString);
    }
    ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayAVR);
    ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    listview.setAdapter(ListAdapter);
    mSqLiteDatabase.close();
    mDatabaseAvrHelper.close();
}
```

Если я вызываю этот метод и родного класса, то работает без проблем.

Когда вызываю его из другого класса, а именно класса наследованного у BroadcastReceiver:

```
Open_Close_AVR ShowDB = new Open_Close_AVR();
ShowDB.ShowDB();
```

вываливается следующая ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.hakeem.avr.SmsBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2616)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:268)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
        at com.hakeem.avr.Open_Close_AVR.ShowDB(Open_Close_AVR.java:125)
        at com.hakeem.avr.SmsBroadcastReceiver.UpdateDB(SmsBroadcastReceiver.java:68)
        at com.hakeem.avr.SmsBroadcastReceiver.SmsFromPdus(SmsBroadcastReceiver.java:42)
        at com.hakeem.avr.SmsBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(SmsBroadcastReceiver.java:27)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2609)
```

Ошибка появляется здесь:

```
mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseAvrHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

Как избежать "on a null object reference"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mDatabaseAvrHelper = new DatabaseAvrHelper(this);
```

Здесь у Вас null, соответственно и в

```
mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseAvrHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

тоже null. Попробуйте в метод context чтоли передавать

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо.